# Dynamically continue list numbering across two different ordered list based on depths with CSS

Tags: css

I have two different ordered lists that are split by a figure tag.

I'd like to continue the numbering across the lists based on the depth classes, and only reset the numbering by the parent depth (e.g. `.depth1` resets the numbering for `.depth2` + `.depth3`)

Right now, the new ordered list is restarting the depth at *a.* and not *c.* like I want. I need the numbering to be dynamic and can't use hard coded values to reset the list.

```css
div.container {
    counter-reset: ol1 ol2 ol3;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.depth1 {
    counter-increment: ol1;
    counter-reset: ol2;
}

li.depth2 { 
    counter-increment: ol2;
    padding-left: 30px; 
    counter-reset: ol3;
}

li.depth3 { 
    counter-increment: ol3;
    padding-left: 60px; 
}

li.depth1:before {
  content: counter(ol1) ". "   !important;
}

li.depth2:before {
  content: counter(ol2, lower-alpha) ". "  !important;
}

li.depth3:before {
     content: counter(ol3, lower-roman) ". "  !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
    </ol>
    <figure><img width="100" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/red-apple.png"/></figure>
    <ol>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

[image: list numbering example]

Answer (score 1):

**First solution**

```
<li class="depth2 depth2_continue">item</li>
```

```
li.depth2.depth2_continue { 
   counter-set: ol2 3;
}
```

```css
div.container {
    counter-reset: ol1 ol2 ol3;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.depth1 {
    counter-increment: ol1;
    counter-reset: ol2;
}

li.depth2 { 
    counter-increment: ol2;
    padding-left: 30px; 
    counter-reset: ol3;
}

li.depth2.depth2_continue { 
   counter-set: ol2 3;
}

li.depth3 { 
    counter-increment: ol3;
    padding-left: 60px; 
}

li.depth1:before {
  content: counter(ol1) ". "   !important;
}

li.depth2:before {
  content: counter(ol2, lower-alpha) ". "  !important;
}

li.depth3:before {
     content: counter(ol3, lower-roman) ". "  !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
    </ol>
    <figure><img width="100" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/red-apple.png"/></figure>
    <ol>
            <li class="depth2 depth2_continue">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**Second solution**

Before:

```
    </ol>
    <figure><img width="100" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/red-apple.png"/></figure>
    <ol>
```

After:

```
    <figure><img width="100" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/red-apple.png"/></figure>
```

```css
div.container {
    counter-reset: ol1 ol2 ol3;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.depth1 {
    counter-increment: ol1;
    counter-reset: ol2;
}

li.depth2 { 
    counter-increment: ol2;
    padding-left: 30px; 
    counter-reset: ol3;
}

li.depth3 { 
    counter-increment: ol3;
    padding-left: 60px; 
}

li.depth1:before {
  content: counter(ol1) ". "   !important;
}

li.depth2:before {
  content: counter(ol2, lower-alpha) ". "  !important;
}

li.depth3:before {
     content: counter(ol3, lower-roman) ". "  !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
    <figure><img width="100" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/red-apple.png"/></figure>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I need the solution to be dynamic and can't hard code the counter-set values (unless there's a way to calculate the last value with CSS)

Comment: best way is solution 2.
can you make example there u want to use it dynamic? mb i can find third solution)

Comment: It's inside a WYSIWYG framework... which is what I meant by dynamic, so the starting depth of 3 could change. To my knowledge, there's no way to calculate the starting depth using CSS. I also can't strip out the OL tag around the image either to merge the lists.

Comment: u can try css variables or dynamic classes then u create html page template. looks like it's not possible using clear css, but with some js it will be easy)

Comment: Agreed, I don't think this is easily possible with CSS and is likely going to require Javascript. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

From OP: I ended up using a `counter-set: counter 0` instead of a counter-reset to restart the numbering after the previous depth. This gets the list to behave as intended.

The only downside here is that [Safari doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/?search=counter-set) counter-set yet. Given that Safari just defaults to the counter-reset behavior, I decided this is an acceptable solution because it covers most other major browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge.

Here's the final code:

```css
div.container {
    counter-reset: ol1 ol2 ol3;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.depth1 {
    counter-increment: ol1;
    counter-set: ol2 0;
}

li.depth2 { 
    counter-increment: ol2;
    padding-left: 30px; 
    counter-set: ol3 0;
}

li.depth3 { 
    counter-increment: ol3;
    padding-left: 60px; 
}

li.depth1:before {
  content: counter(ol1) ". ";
}

li.depth2:before {
  content: counter(ol2, lower-alpha) ". ";
}

li.depth3:before {
     content: counter(ol3, lower-roman) ". ";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
            <li class="depth3">item</li>
    </ol>
    <figure><img width="100" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/red-apple.png"/></figure>
    <ol>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
            <li class="depth2">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
                <li class="depth3">item</li>
        <li class="depth2">item</li>
        <li class="depth1">item</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```